# Function unmounted but still executing on eventlistener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've unmounted my function which is binded to the window event listener. Still, after going to the next page the function inside the event still executes although being removed? What might be the problem here?

```
   componentDidMount(){
     window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions.bind(this));
   }
   componentWillUnmount(){
     console.log("unmounting....");
     window.removeEventListener('resize', this.updateDimensions.bind(this));
   }
```

Here is the function which is binded-attached to the event:

```
 updateDimensions(){
      if (this.refs.get_it.clientWidth < 774){
         this.setState({
         width:this.refs.get_it.clientWidth,
         height:400,
         flag:true});
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is slight confusion in your code

```
 componentDidMount(){
      window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions.bind(this)); 
      // first instance listening to event
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
      console.log("unmounting....");
      window.removeEventListener('resize', this.updateDimensions.bind(this));
      // second instance removed from listener here first!== second
    }
```

Try this

```
 constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.updateDimensions = this.updateDimensions.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount(){
      window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions);
      // first instance listening to event
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
      console.log("unmounting....");
      window.removeEventListener('resize', this.updateDimensions);
      // same instance removed from listener here first == second
    }
```

Comment: just wanted to write the same -_-

Comment: Tnx a lot, saved me time, always will bind my methods in the constructor from now on, bad practice..

Comment: Pleasure to help you. Can you also accept the answer :)

Comment: Or define method as bound class method: `updateDimensions = (...args) => {/*code*/}`