# document.removeEventListner not removing event in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, mouseevent

uI have react component, I use `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook to bind `mousedown` event to **document**. When mouse down event triggering I bind two more events `mousemove` and `mouseup` to **document** also I remove those events at `mouseup` event.

My problem is when `mouseup` event triggering it suppose to remove `mousemove` and `mouseup` but its not working. Instead each time I click the page `mouseup` triggering multiple times like: 1, 3, 6, 10, 15... it's multiplying.

When `componentWillUnmount` also not removing event from **document**.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class SandBox extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mouseDown.bind(this))
    }

    //mouseDown
    mouseDown(){
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseUp.bind(this))
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseMove.bind(this))
    }

    //mouseUp
    mouseUp(){
        // this is not removing the events from document
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseUp, false)
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseMove, false)
        // this triggers 1,3,6,10,15 times
        console.log('mose up')
    }

    moseMove(){
        // mosemoveCodes
    }

}
```

Comment: use forceUpdate maybe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function unmounted but still executing on eventlistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133311/function-unmounted-but-still-executing-on-eventlistener)

Comment: @duwalanise its not the same problem, my question is i cant remove events. that question is event triggering after component unmount.

Comment: @ColorPlayers I see similarity in between these two questions because in both cases same method has to be passed to add and remove eventListener which was mistaken. and yeah there could be little difference in execution. Never mind :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `bind` on function it will make new function and you cant reference old this.whatever thats why `removeEventlistener` cannot find your function. you can fix this with using es6 `class` `constructor`.

```
class YourComponent extends Component {
   constructor(props){
     super(props)
     //bind and reference your methods here
     this.mouseDown = this.mouseDown.bind(this)
     this.mouseUp = this.mouseUp.bind(this)
     this.mouseMove = this.mouseMove.bind(this)
     // now its pointing corectcly
   }
   // lifecycle
   componentDidMount(){
     document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mouseDown.bind(this))
   }
   //mouseDown
   mouseDown(){
     document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseUp)
     document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseMove)
   }

   //mouseUp
   mouseUp(){
     // this is will work
     document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseUp, false)
     document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseMove, false)

     console.log('mouse up')
   }
    // unmount
   componentWillUnmount(){
     // this is will work
     document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.mouseDown, false)
   }
}
```